# Initiating a download with javascript

Tags: javascript, download

I need to dynamically initiate a download with javascript. I have seen how people do this by doing something like

```
window.open("some url", "Download");
```

but I need to do it without changing the url of the current page (and not using frames if I can help it, or created and destroying a frame dynamically). Anybody know how to do this?

Comment: window.open does not change the url of the current page. It opens a new page (unless the pop-up blocker stops it).

Comment: In chrome it does nothing, and I need a cross-browser method as well.

Comment: Oh actually I was wrong, Chrome didn't even tell me it was blocking popups. Thanks.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You don't need `window.open()`. It's plain ugly and prone to popupblockers (where you have no control over in clients). Just `window.location` is sufficient if the response header of the requested download URL contains `Content-Disposition: attachment`. This won't change the current URL in the browser address bar nor the current page, but just pop a *Save As* dialogue.

E.g.

```
window.location = 'http://download.winzip.com/winzip145.exe';
```

Comment: This works fine for `.exe` files, but not for files the browser is capable of rendering, like an image, pdf, or html file.

Comment: In a typed environment it is better to use `assign()` because location is an object of type Location which cannot be assigned a string: `window.location.assign('http://download.winzip.com/winzip145.exe');`.
But booth variants are fully supported: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location

Comment: This works for PDF files in both Firefox and Chrome when I tried it, as long as the `Content-Disposition` header is set correctly.