# Initiate download and execute action?

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I've got a link which is supposed to execute an action and initiate a download.
However as soon as an `{{action}}` ist set the `href`attribute is suppressed.

```
<a {{bind-attr href=download.filepath}} {{ action "incDownload"  }}>
    {{ download.name }}
</a>
```

How can I make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass the filepath as a parameter to the action instead and initiate the download in the action.

```
<a {{ action "incDownload" download.filepath }}>
    {{ download.name }}
</a>
```

and then your action will have access to the filepath:

```
incDownload: function(filepath){
   // do stuff

   // peform the download
   window.location = filepath;
}
```

Comment: That's what I thought as well but how can I do that?

Comment: haha thanks. I know how actions and their arguments work but not how I initiate a download from an action itself. Sorry for not making that clear.

Comment: That's as easy as setting `window.location` - see http://stackoverflow.com/a/3645025/77074 - I updated my answer.