# How to preventDefault() for a simulated click()

Tags: javascript

I want to allow download from a cloud URL like below. Can i prevent default refresh of the page on this click ?

```
/* Server responded with a url and filename */

let a=document.createElement('a');
document.body.appendChild(a);
a.href=url ;
a.download =filename
a.click();
```

I tried this method to prevent refresh.

```
function tempClick(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   window.open(e.target.href);
}

a.addEventListener('click',tempClick);
a.click();
```

I would like a better method to trigger the download than the intrusive window.open()

Comment: Not sure what you want – do you need a way to prevent the default action or do you need an alternative for `window.open`?

Comment: Besides: I'm not entirely convinced by the idea to automatically download stuff (it seems you are trying to do exactly that). Why can't you just display the link to the user so he can decide?

Comment: Don't use a link, use [*XMLHttp​Request*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) to get the data.

Comment: RobG, the url and filename is from the response of XMLHttpRequest.
David, the url is fetched on the click of a button. Neither the link nor the file is known(exists even) before the click of the actual UI button. 

Hence, I am forced to append the anchor tag and creating the click event to start the download ?

Answer (score 1):

Interesting problem.

Did you already try the [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3644938/initiating-a-download-with-javascript) recommended "window.location.assign()" or simply "window.location = url;" way? It seems that it can work if your file is not renderable by the browser and/or responds with the correct "Content-Disposition" type.

Note: I did not find a file to check for except an image. However, the image just opens in the browser when using "window.location.assign()" (which of course is not what you want)...

Edit: Of course, then you would not need the .click() at all but simply execute window.location.assign()

Comment: The file is a csv. It could be 1GB as well and should not be rendered in browser.

Comment: Btw. just stumbled over this too. Maybe it still helps: https://davidwalsh.name/javascript-download